# Why don't I see the colorbutton plugin in CKEditor?

Tags: input-formats

I installed the [Colorbutton module](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbutton/) and its composer dependencies:

```
"drupal/colorbutton": "^1",
"drupal-ckeditor-libraries-group/colorbutton": "^4.14",
"drupal-ckeditor-libraries-group/panelbutton": "^4.14",
```

I then enabled the module, configured the **Basic HTML** text form, and added the new buttons to my toolbar.

However, I don't see the buttons as an authenticated user (admin or regular authenticated user).

I rebuilt the Drupal cache, cleared the browser cache... Still the same problem.

How do I display the color buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, **Basic HTML** strips `<span style>` attributes, which CKEditor uses to apply color.

On `/admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html`, if you add `<span style>` to the **Allowed HTML Tags**, the buttons will be displayed.

Comment: All of this is mentioned in the [README.txt](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/colorbutton/-/blob/8.x-1.x/README.txt)